# Loading Spinner inside the InAppBrowser Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a IonicLoading Spinner inside the InAppBrowser while the page loads.
This is what i am doing:

```html
<button class="button" ng-controller="View" ng-click="showHelp('http://www.google.com')">
</button>
```

Controller:

```js
.controller('View', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

 $scope.showHelp=function(url) {
 var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(){ $ionicLoading.show(); }); 
 ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { $ionicLoading.hide(); });
 
 }
})
```

The issue is the spinner doesn't load inside the InAppBrowser instead it shows in the background (i.e. visible only if i close the InAppBrowser)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788102/ionic-show-spinner-after-button-is-pressed/37812549#37812549 check this answer it will work surely

Comment: Thanks for replying, the answer posted below by Arpit works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `inAppBrowser` stays on top of the `WebView`, you cannot add a `Loader` using HTML. You can add a native Loader after adding the `cordova-plugin-dialogs` plugin. Here is some code to get you started:

**To start loading:**

```
navigator.notification.activityStart("Please Wait", "Its loading.....");
```

**To stop Loader:**

```
navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

If you need more information, check [this](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/02/show-loading-screen-in-phonegap-app.html) reference.

Comment: glad, I could help.

Comment: Posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845293/ionic-list-animation-repeat

Answer (score 6):

I am working with ionic V2+ (ionic 3 ) app and I used `cordova-plugin-dialogs` but it did not work for me as I expected. I used [Spinner Dialog](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/spinner-dialog/) and work well. Please find the sample code below

**Installing plugin**

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-native-spinner`

`npm install --save @ionic-native/spinner-dialog`

**Code**

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { SpinnerDialog } from '@ionic-native/spinner-dialog';

constructor(
private iab: InAppBrowser,
private spinnerDialog: SpinnerDialog) { }

...

 const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.google.com',
  '_blank',
  {
    location: 'no',
    clearcache: 'yes',
    clearsessioncache: 'yes'
  });

browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((eve) => {
  this.spinnerDialog.show(null, null, true);     
}, err => {
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
})

browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(()=>{
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
}, err =>{
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
})

browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(()=>{
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
}, err =>{
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
})

browser.on('exit').subscribe(()=>{
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
}, err =>{
  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my day. But please remove your cordova-plugin-dialogs installation code and replace spinned and in app browser installation code.

Comment: @Karnan Muthukumar thank you lot buddy I didn't see it. I corrected my mistake :)

Comment: import changed in ionic 4 ``import { SpinnerDialog } from '@ionic-native/spinner-dialog/ngx';``

Comment: @JithinLukose thank you!. you could update the answer if it is the right way to do this now. because I did not work with ionic recently. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the `activityStop` is deprecated I recommend the following method to prevent InAppBrowser's blank opening screen

Open the InAppBrowser in hidden mode and later in `loadstop` event show the InAppBrowser. Till then you can show ionic loader or your custom loader

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
  $ionicLoading.show(); /*or `showLoader()`*/
}); //`showLoader()` is your own loader function to show loader within your app
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
  ref.show();
  $ionicLoading.hide(); /*or `hideLoader()`*/
}); //`hideLoader()` is your own loader function to hide loader within your app
```