# Ionic list animation repeat

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Animation (ionicMaterialMotion) from https://github.com/zachfitz/Ionic-Material

I am animating a list by

```
<ion-list class="animate-ripple">
```

The issue is that the animation is played only once, when the tab is first loaded. While switching to other tab and returning, it doesn't animate.
I have tried disabling cache for that particular view by

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: as ionic-material is in alpha. I'd advice you to use [MDlite](http://getmdl.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference but i don't think they have Material Motion implemented, at least not that i could find.