# how do i show ionic loading until local storage is populated in pouch

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I have used service for storing data in local storage using pouchDB. I would like to show ionic loading until the data are downloaded and stored locally. For now I have used timeout which is not an option for me.

My Service

```
function populateLocaldb() {
        var count; 
        _localdb.info().then(function(d){
                    console.log(d.doc_count)
                    count = d.doc_count;

            if(count===0) {
                populateData1();
                populateData2();
                populateData3();
            } else {

            }           
        });
    }
function populateChapter() {
        $http.get('http://....').success(function(data) {
                    //console.log(data)
                    var values= data;
                    for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {               
                        var value= {
                                _id: values[i].ID,        
                                title: chapters[i].Title
                            }
                                _localdb.put(value, function callback(err, result) {
                                    if (!err) {
                                      console.log('Successfully posted a value!');
                                    }
                                  });

                    }
                })
    }
```

Controller

```
dbService.getAllinfo().then(function(data) {
    if(data == ""){
      //do nothing
      //alert(" null Alert hello")
      console.log(data)
      $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      }).then(function() {
        dbService.populateLocaldb();
      });
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
  })

  $timeout(function () {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, 50000);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788102/ionic-show-spinner-after-button-is-pressed/37812549#37812549 check this answer you it as your wish

Comment: I want to call $ionicLoading.hide() after my service for storing data in local storage is called. I tried doing them but the problem I faced is the ionic loading code (both show and hide) is executed first and then only the downloading process. I want to show loading sign until the contents are downloaded and stored in local storage without putting timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to call `$scope.$apply()` in the PouchDB callback. Also, another tip: instead of doing multiple `put()s` inside of a `forEach()`, it's more efficient in PouchDB to do a single `bulkDocs()` operation.